# PHP: User id dynamic pages

Tags: php, dynamic-pages

*Hi*
I am making a website where the users can visit eachother.
Therefore i need to make dynamic pages so that if i go to let's say...

```
www.mypage.net/user.php?id=32
```

Then i would end up on John Smiths profile, and show his profile.
And if i went to id=54 then, my own profile would be shown. 
I was just wondering, how would i go forward on this?
I already have the user id stored in a session when the user logs in, but how do i create the url so it looks like ?id=32    and not onlye user.php ?

Is there any good tutorials explaining this?
Thx in advance!

Comment: Is this a beginners question or do I just don't understand your question?

Comment: This is a beginners question, sorry. I don't know how to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can already sense that you are gonna get lots of downvotes. That's because, you are not showing any effort and asking about stuff, that can be easily found on the net.

This is the basic of what you want:

```
$userid = (isset($_GET['uid']) ? $_GET['uid'] : NULL);

if ($userid) {
    $userinfo = $DB->query_first("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$userid'");
    print_r($userinfo);
}
```

You can already see, that you need to read about [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and of course about [mysql querying](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/).

Further more, these types of concept related questions are more fit to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). You should read [SO's faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

All parameters passed through the URL query are stored in a global array called `$_GET` in php. So if you go to let's say `www.mypage.net/user.php?id=32` in you PHP code, you can access that value like this. `$_GET['id']`. e.g

```
echo "Hello user number " . $_GET['id'] . "<br /> How are you today?";
```

I can't find a decent tutorial on $_GET but you can try this, hopefully it helps

http://www.tutorialarena.com/php/php-get-tutorial.php

Comment: Thank you, i will look into the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just type in that URL. That's a general method to pass parameters to your PHP script. Parameters specified in the URL are called GET-parameters. In the script itself, you can access these by checking `$_GET['id']`. GET-parameters have the following scheme:

```
URL.to.your.script.php?name=value&name2=value2&...
```

I.e. parameters are seperated by an ampersand and have always the scheme "name" equals "value". The name you specifiy in the URL is then availble in the `$_GET` array.

Another way of passing parameters is using POST. You do this generally when submitting data from Forms so that their values don't show up in URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you place a link in your html somewhere with the querystring ?id (like: www.mypage.net/user.php?id=32), you can get the url by using $_GET['id'] in your PHP code.

Maybe this link can help [php for beginners](http://php.scriptkiddies.nl/)